# Typescript type with property of name given as parameter

Tags: typescript

I want a typescript type with a named property such that the name is **provided dynamically**, whilst also containing some other properties.

Something like:

```
type ItemWithNamespaceFlag<flagName>{
   name: string,
   color: "red"|"blue",
   [flagName]: boolean
}

let myRuntimeProperty: string = getStringFromSomewhere();
const ItemWithProperty: ItemWithNamespaceFlag<myRuntimeProperty>{
   name: "foo",
   color: "red",
   [myRuntimeProperty]: true
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want *unique types* as per [ms/TS#4895](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4895); these can be simulated with branding, but it doesn't really work the way you want as a key type. If `flagName` were a symbol instead of a string you could get similar behavior out of `unique symbol` like [this](//tsplay.dev/WK9gGN); you might even be able to use this version and just lie to the compiler that `myRuntimeProperty` is a symbol instead of a string... but I don't know if that fits your use case. Does this fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Wow, very detailed answer! That's exactly what I want, thank you! Still gotta lie to the compiler sometimes I guess...

Comment: Okay I’ll write up an answer post when I get a chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the output of `getStringFromSomewhere()` to be a "unique" `string` type (let's call it `MyRuntimeProperty`) whose value you don't really know or care about; instead you want to "tag" it so that the compiler will only allow you to assign the same unique/tagged value as the key of `ItemWithNamespaceFlag`.  This is similar to [nominal typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), where `MyRuntimeProperty` would be a special subtype of `string` that isn't considered mutually compatible with other `string` types.

There are various feature requests for this sort of thing, such as `unique` types requested at [microsoft/TypeScript#4895](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4895), but nothing is implemented.  There are also various ways to simulate/emulate this sort of thing, such as [branding](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) (e.g., `type MyRuntimeProperty = string & {__myRuntimeProperty}`) , but unfortunately branded keys won't act the way you want.

---

So you'll need to work around it.  Probably the simplest workaround is to pick a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) and *pretend* that this is the value you're going to have at runtime:

```
type MyRuntimeProperty =
  "__[[myRuntimeProperty]]__DO_NOT_USE_THIS_STRING_LITERAL"; // or whatever
```

Pick whatever string literal value you want, as long as it sufficiently discourages people from using the actual literal value.  You're lying to the compiler about what the value is, but mostly a white lie.

Anyway, then things will just "work" for the most part:

```
declare function getStringFromSomewhere(): MyRuntimeProperty;
const myRuntimeProperty = getStringFromSomewhere();

interface ItemWithNamespaceFlag {
    name: string,
    color: "red" | "blue",
    [myRuntimeProperty]: boolean
};

const itemWithProperty: ItemWithNamespaceFlag = {
    name: "foo",
    color: "red",
    [myRuntimeProperty]: true
}

const v = itemWithProperty[myRuntimeProperty]
// const v: boolean
```

Technically nothing stops someone from writing

```
const k: MyRuntimeProperty = "__[[myRuntimeProperty]]__DO_NOT_USE_THIS_STRING_LITERAL"; 
itemWithProperty["__[[myRuntimeProperty]]__DO_NOT_USE_THIS_STRING_LITERAL"]
```

in TypeScript, which would almost certainly fail at runtime.  But hopefully anyone who does so will feel very ashamed of themselves.

---

A slightly more complicated workaround is to pretend to use a string [`enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) which itself pretends to use a string literal:

```
const enum MyRuntimeProperty {
    "[[PretendKey]]" = "__[[myRuntimeProperty]]__DO_NOT_USE_THIS_STRING_LITERAL"
}
```

This is treated a little more nominally than the plain string literal from before, in that now

```
const k: MyRuntimeProperty = "__[[myRuntimeProperty]]__DO_NOT_USE_THIS_STRING_LITERAL" // error
```

is an error, but object keys lose their enum-ness, so

```
itemWithProperty["__[[myRuntimeProperty]]__DO_NOT_USE_THIS_STRING_LITERAL"]
```

is still allowed.

---

Another approach is to use [`unique symbol`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol) instead of a string type.  JavaScript allows the use of [symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) as unique keys, and TypeScript has the concept of `unique symbol` which acts as a nominal type, so no two separate declarations of `unique symbol` are compatible with each other.  And TypeScript has explicit support for symbolic keys in a way that doesn't work for branded/tagged/enum strings.  Of course your runtime string will definitely not be a symbol, so this is a bigger lie than the string literal... but it still works:

```
declare const MyRuntimeProperty: unique symbol
type MyRuntimeProperty = typeof MyRuntimeProperty;

declare function getStringFromSomewhere(): MyRuntimeProperty;
const myRuntimeProperty: MyRuntimeProperty = getStringFromSomewhere();
// need annotation ----> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

interface ItemWithNamespaceFlag {
    name: string,
    color: "red" | "blue",
    [myRuntimeProperty]: boolean
};

const itemWithProperty: ItemWithNamespaceFlag = {
    name: "foo",
    color: "red",
    [myRuntimeProperty]: true
}

const v = itemWithProperty[myRuntimeProperty]
// const v: boolean
```

And now there's no way you could even try to use a string literal key to access the `myRuntimeProperty` property, because the compiler thinks it's a symbol, and it will only let you use the symbol that comes from `myRuntimeProperty` or the output of `getStringFromSomewhere()`.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFAThALhYATAypmgJbADmAMsdmiADZIDeAUEm0pgJ4zICynAJQCuwTMUjoA9jzRckAXiQAiAPoqA2urCCRYiWmkRZnALom1AEQDyKgHJWAKioCq+AKIqHACQCS+FfgOAj62AOIqFD4ObgIAghRKANzMrOy4EPB0IBhIAGYi8GKSwEhkWIQk5ABiBmD4kpAA7gAWRhAAFACUAFxI-MKi4hBSMlzJ7EjwxVCYSNoDesMGo5wKpeVEpGQ1DfVNrRhdyalspDS5CMg+2GAA6tTNtuDQcIhVWWRMJxNIoJC9M0qZAANN8JlM6JI0L0lBhcEokAAfZQAIzoQggSlBP3YWh0g30hmMJl6KMkkjoEBAwG+AF9juDprNqBA7g8RkYuL1rqz7phHs9YJd3iBPooWDi2H8IDDcuSsWD2BCoTC4QrJUg8Qshhzib0iBi6SlGcAZkgAG5rFls-m6rha3Q65ac0zfAD0bsmTItpPJlOpxqV3oA1r1+o7CSs1qoNA6CUsiVwzJYbPYnK4PN4-AEgiFwpFonEEkgPUgADwAWgrSGakkaSFw2WQnEkQm+1r5zTtnHUMc08wjCZWyZU1jsjhc7k8vn8gWCYQiURi8SUJhLnsr1a8VluSAssQEbiQAE0rM5mLSUtKhYhUBhsHg3MAhGAvt8pqbZjgX318Ytu18GpKJo6BYDguAANIQKYJgIoofZxv+zrEuYo6phOGbTtmc55ouhYrka3zpJkTZ5AURQlGUmAVFsOx1A0EAtG0XRhn+TqJpw4xBp+cxsZGLprFRNHVLUeyMQcHSdAy7BnEYFy3jyNoCpAN4QCKnwSpK0oAps5DYpKyrQsoapIqi6KYvpOKIexw6+hSVI0hM9KBmwH5mh27LIVySCKZ2Twqa8akfGsmk4tpyhypI6oGRSKrGRA8KWT81n8XqHBoIaTkuV6PGWooHm2l5PYDvG3YmO6npubM5p2f6NLviGrHaqlcjwWo-Z8UOLojmOaaTpmM45vO+ZLkWCKlkYBhoO2Nydt2vbtSlXUoSm47plOWazrmC4FsuCRrqWm5INuu77oeJ5nheKTMNegV3mBeD4JwYBkgwoUNhkWQ5FVv7Nct3kiMQACOGJIFAz2vd8XA8L9g4AYo0MQJIuSw6VRXSWwxFfcg+TAIUxDFOs1G6dsokMUxhw9KjSEcVxrneiVNMrE1cNFYJGxAnRYkU5JdPrr8EAJUg1LAJImAgBRSBVlWAB8SAAHqK0rysq8r2WyWg8lXLNDz+S8wrBe9EzhYCWxJYykJGbCCUIsiShohi0VWYzNndbVDl0hjOXuTrhUcdyvvKfrbzBeKipSs8sryubQaW6qNsx2wS1lfqGUQIRJpmnlSAFV2RXJ0V5UTKWP01UgZL2QG3wpJeQA)

Answer (score 2):

(This answers the original question where `FlagName` was not dynamic).

Use [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types): [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsDqBLYALAcgQwRAzmNgMYQBiANtgOYA8lNOeUEAHvAHYAm%20U%20wAJxQdqAPigBeKAG8AUFAUdcEAFx9Bw6gBp5C4gHsK%20gWoBEAiF1MAfUwCMKAVwimdAXygAyKACUIBgS56KmomCC0oO31DCGwOUVlZAw5%20WHgEGA4wwhIIAEY1OERUDGyiUgY6UxS803EpOQUoJTwzADNo110oAyMTKHNLLqaatUFnWTcgA)

```js
type ItemWithNamespaceFlag<FlagName extends string> = {
   name: string,
   color: "red" | "blue",
} & Record<FlagName, boolean>
```

Comment: Aha! but FlagName must be a literal... what if Flagname was dynamic?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? You can edit the question to better show the use case.

Comment: It can't be done. Typescript has no way of knowing at compile-time what `getStringFromSomewhere` will return at runtime. The most you can do is define the property like this: `flag: { name: string, value: boolean }`.

Comment: Ah dang, I suspected this would be the case. Thanks anyway!